# Java lambda argument type not inferred correctly

Tags: java, lambda

I'm trying to call this method on javafx: `TableColumn.setOnEditCommit`. This method's definition is the following:

```
public final void setOnEditCommit(EventHandler<CellEditEvent<S,T>> value) {
    // ...
}
```

As you can see, it explicitely requires an `EventHandler` of type `CellEditEvent` (which extends `Event`). The `EventHandler`'s definition:

```
public interface EventHandler<T extends Event> extends EventListener {
    void handle(T event);
}
```

Obvious enough, to call `setOnEditCommit` (without lamba), one would type this:

```
column.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent>() {
    public void handle(CellEditEvent event) {
        event.getTableView().doSomething();
    }
});
```

*Note: `getTableView` is a method of `CellEditEvent`, but not of `Event`.*

All nice so far. The problem I've come into is that writing the above code seems to be impossible using lambda, without casting. That is, the lamba equivalent for the above is:

```
column.setOnEditCommit(event -> event.getTableView().doSomething());
```

Here's the problem. `Lambda` doesn't care that the event should be a `CellEditEvent` because the `setOnEditCommit` method explicitely states the `EventHandler`'s vararg is a `CellEditEvent`.

Apparently, when inferring argument types, lambda checks out the `EventHandler` class definition, in particular the `<T extends Event>` part, and then decides that T is an `Event`, and that's it, not that t *extends* `Event`. In this case, the error thrown is that method 'getTableView' is not found - because the `Event` class doesn't have that method.

Not only that, but not even explicitely stating the argument type doesn't work:

```
column.setOnEditCommit((TableColumn.CellEditEvent event) -> event.getTableView().doSomething());
```

Results in the error:

> Error:(10, 32) java: incompatible types: incompatible parameter types in lambda expression

My question is: Why doesn't lambda correctly infer that the argument should be `T extends Event` (`CellEditEvent` in this case), not `Event`, and is there any way to fix that?

Full example:

```
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TableColumn column = null;
        column.setOnEditCommit(event -> event.getTableView());
    }
}
```

Comment: Your non-lambda code is using raw types. I suspect the rest of the code also does. Make sure you're not using any raw type. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: @jb-nizet Don't worry, I never use raw types in my code. I only did that to simplify the code as much as possible. Also, I added a full source code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently using raw types for the `TableColumn` causes this issue to happen. So this will work:

```
TableColumn<SomeClass, SomeOtherClass> column = null;
column.setOnEditCommit(event -> event.getTableView());
```

Not only that, but also this:

```
TableColumn<?, ?> column = null;
column.setOnEditCommit(event -> event.getTableView());
```

But this will not:

```
TableColumn column = null;
column.setOnEditCommit(event -> event.getTableView());
```

Comment: I told ya I suspected raw types being used :-)

Answer (score 2):

The compiler doesn't have that type information.
The only information the compiler has is this:

```
public interface EventHandler<T extends Event> extends EventListener {
    void handle(T event);
}
```

Now you want to use it like that:

```
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TableColumn column = null;
        column.setOnEditCommit(event -> event.getTableView());
    }
}
```

How is the compiler supposed to determine the type of event? The type CellEditEvent does not appear anywhere.

In this case, you have to explicitely specify the type you want.

```
column.setOnEditCommit((TableColumn.CellEditEvent event) -> event.getTableView().doSomething());
```

Comment: This is not an answer. My question is, why isn't the argument inferred correctly, if if there any way around this _without casts_. Please read the whole question before answering.

Comment: Of course it is an answer. Because the compiler doesn't have that information. How should it know that you want it to be of type CellEditEvent? Note that the type annotation in my answer is not a cast.

Comment: Sorry, I meant it is not an answer to my question. My question is: "why doesn't lambda correctly infer that the argument should be T extends Event(CellEditEvent in this case), not Event". Your answer doesn't attempt to answer that.

Comment: Of course it is. Please read my last comment: Because the compiler doesn't have that information. How should it know that you want it to be of type CellEditEvent? Note that the type annotation in my answer is not a cast.

Comment: It should know that it's of CellEditEvent because of the method declaration.

Comment: My bad, it's not a cast but I kinda meant without explicitely naming the type. Also I can't do anything unless you edit your answer.

Comment: What you "kinda meant" and what you wrote are two different pairs of shoes, it's your bad if you don't use proper terms. I edited my answer and provided more details.

Comment: Either way, your answer does not work, it results in the error "Error: java: incompatible types: incompatible parameter types in lambda expression". IntelliJ details this and says "expected Event but found CellEditEvent". So it's actually impossible without casting.

Comment: @Chaoz the compiler doesn't care what *actual* type your object is, only what it's *declared* as. +1

Comment: @Bohemian read my latest comment; this answer is not working, which means that the compiler doesn't care about either the actual type or what it's declared as.